# If check producing "Compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time error"

Tags: xcode, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I am working on a book iOS app that utilizes Google Firebase. I just restarted this project after 10 months of inactive period and thus had to update many things to comply with my new m1 computer as well as software changes. There was one view called SavedBooks that had previously worked and it essentially cross-checked the Firestore database to the books available. Users are able to save books they like from another view and that would put a marker on the database which the SavedBooks view checked for. However, this view has been giving the `Compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time` error ever since the restart.

I've posted a "Skeleton" of view that reproduces the error. The nested views were necessary to produce an intended UI. The challenge I faced is the error persists even when trying to break them down to other views and use @Binding to pass Observable data. I can't easily break things up because a lot of the data needs to be fed/retrieved real time and passed between the views.

Anyhow, I can't imagine the attached code would be so difficult for Xcode to do a type check and produce a view. It compiles happily when using something like  `Text("Hello")` inside the deepest if conditional. The frustrating thing is that when I include anything associated with the identifiable classes book and user (that need to be fetched from Firebase) I get an error - so it's not just the button. And I've also tried newer syntaxes like a label for the button so confident it's not because of that.

It is a hard one to replicate because it involves Firebase, but any input is appreciated.

```
import SwiftUI
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import SDWebImageSwiftUI
import CoreData
import AVKit
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import FirebaseFirestoreSwift
import Foundation

import SwiftUI

struct SavedBooks: View {
    @State var user_ID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid ?? ""
    @ObservedObject var consumer = getUserInfo()
    @ObservedObject var books = getBooks()
    @State var book_detail : books_Data?
    @State var liked_array = []
    @State var count = 0
    @State var width = CGFloat.zero
    @State var height = CGFloat.zero
    @State var multi_Color = true
    @State var rem_Num = 0.0
    @State var rem_Str = ""
    @State var watch_Num = "0.0"
    @State var liked_Str = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        //iterate on consumers (will be one since only one user signs in)
                        ForEach(self.consumer.datas) { user in
                            //iterate on available books
                            ForEach(self.books.datas) { books in
                                VStack {
                                    ForEach(user.loved, id: \.self) { item in
                                            //if the current book was liked by the user, do the following
                                            if(books.id == item){
                                                VStack {
                                                    Button(action: {
                                                        self.book_detail = books //
                                                    }) {
                                                        
                                                        if let url = URL(string: books.largeImg) {
                                                                AnimatedImage(url: url)
                                                                    .resizable()
                                                                    .frame(width: 60, height: 90)
                                                                    .clipped()
                                                                    .cornerRadius(8)
                                                                    .overlay(
                                                                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                                                            .stroke(Color(white: 0.4))
                                                                    )
                                                                    .shadow(radius: 3)
                                                        }
                                                }
                                            }
                                    }//ForEach
                                }//VStack
                            }//ForEach books
                        }//ForEach users (only accessing one user account)
                    }//ScrollView
                }//HStack
            }//VStack
        }//ZStack
        //onAppear is used to load up to date information from Firebase
        .onAppear{
            self.consumer.retrieveData()
            self.books.retrieveData()
        }
    }
}
```

These are the assisting Observable objects:

```
struct books_Data : Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var title: String
    var largeImg: String
}

class getBooks : ObservableObject{
    @Published var datas = [books_Data]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    
    func retrieveData(){
        db.collection("movies").addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let mov = querySnapshot?.documents else{
                print("No movies")
                return
            }
            
            self.datas = mov.map{(queryDocumentSnapshot) -> books_Data in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                let title = data["title"] as? String ?? ""
                let largeImg = data["largeImg"] as? String ?? ""
                
                
                return books_Data(id: id, title: title, largeImg: largeImg)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct userInfo : Identifiable {
    var id: String
    var firstName: String
    var lastName: String
    var emailAddress: String
    var loved: Array<String>
}


class getUserInfo : ObservableObject{
    @Published var datas = [userInfo]()
    private var db = Firestore.firestore()
    @State private var userID = Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid
    
    func retrieveData(){
        db.collection("users").whereField("id", isEqualTo: self.userID).addSnapshotListener{ (querySnapshot, error) in
            guard let mov = querySnapshot?.documents else{
                print("No User")
                return
            }
            
            self.datas = mov.map{(queryDocumentSnapshot) -> userInfo in
                let data = queryDocumentSnapshot.data()
                let id = data["id"] as? String ?? ""
                let firstName = data["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
                let lastName = data["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
                let emailAddress = data["emailAddress"] as? String ?? ""
                let loved = data["loved"] as? Array<String> ?? []
                
                return userInfo(id: id, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, emailAddress: emailAddress, loved: loved)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: The problem is probably linked to the **inner if statement**. As shown in the below screenshots, the project compiles if I remove that conditional and gives the error when I include it. I even tried trimming most of the views and doing a one liner conditional to assign the book information to State variables, and it still gave an error.

There surely is a type check issue because if I just assign without a conditional, it works. Is there anything I need to know with if checks that can produce this error with the newest version of Xcode? This should've been a simple comparison of similar type objects to check if the book is liked and preview it.

- Error screenshot below when if statement is included
  [image]
- Working screenshot below when if statement is commented out
  [image]

Comment: The common practice on such error is to break huge views on smaller separated sub-views to simplify structure.

Comment: Yes, and I've been trying to do that but it has made it much complicated because the views are producing live data and it is a pain passing those variables. My confusion is Xcode not giving such errors for my other views which are even more nested than this. The inner if check is the only unique part that is preventing it from understanding the code and I'm not sure why that is given it's a simple conditional.

Comment: Don't know if this will help with your compiler issues, but instead of `ForEach(user.loved...) { item in if books.id == item...`, you could drop the `ForEach` and instead use `if user.loved.contains(books.id)`. It's certainly simpler, which _might_ help the compiler, but it'll be a lot faster at runtime if your user has loved a lot of books…

Comment: That's a lot of code for us to parse through and the question itself is a bit unclear. Are you receiving an actual error? If so, what line does it appear on. Then... when you step through your code leading up to that error, which var isn't as expected? Some basic troubleshooting would help us understand the issue.

Comment: @ScottMatthewman I used ForEach because there can be multiple books in the loved array. Thus, using something like if.user.loved[0].contains(book.id) won't cover every case. I did however tried to eliminate the ForEach(self.consumer.datas) { user in and use self.consumer.datas[0] since there's only one user. But that also doesn't solve the error.

Comment: @Jay I apologize for not explaining the question better. The `Compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time` error shows up on the right side of the parenthesis on `var body: some View {`. Stepping into the code, if I just add a Text() object inside the innermost if statement, the code will compile. However, just having a button object that is trying to set book detail to the identifiable book object will cause the error. I will attach a screenshot of the error above.

Comment: @Jay the issue is likely linked to the if conditional. Please view the edited description and screenshots for reference.

Comment: @Asperi any ideas on the new edits? I trimmed most of the view and still seeing the error. It must be a type-check related issue with the if check because otherwise it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to break your view up a little to help the type checker out.

Ideally what you should do is create a set of View structs so you don't have the *pyramid of doom* you have at the moment.

But, in the meantime, what you can do is simply move a coherent chunk of code out into a separate method, tag it as a ViewBuilder, and you should be able to find a refactoring that works.

I'd do something like this:

```swift
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    ScrollView(.vertical, showsIndicators: false) {
                        //iterate on consumers (will be one since only one user signs in)
                        ForEach(self.consumer.datas) { user in
                            //iterate on available books
                            ForEach(self.books.datas) { books in
                                userView(user, books)
                            }//ForEach books
                        }//ForEach users (only accessing one user account)
                    }//ScrollView
                }//HStack
            }//VStack
        }//ZStack
        //onAppear is used to load up to date information from Firebase
        .onAppear{
            self.consumer.retrieveData()
            self.books.retrieveData()
        }
    }

    @ViewBuilder
    func userView(_ user: userInfo, _ books: books_Data) -> some View {
        VStack {
           ForEach(user.loved, id: \.self) { item in
//                    //if the current book was liked by the user, do the following
                    if(books.id == item){
                        VStack {
                            Button(action: {
                                self.book_detail = books //
                            }) {

                                if let url = URL(string: books.largeImg) {
                                        AnimatedImage(url: url)
                                            .resizable()
                                            .frame(width: 60, height: 90)
                                            .clipped()
                                            .cornerRadius(8)
                                            .overlay(
                                                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                                                    .stroke(Color(white: 0.4))
                                            )
                                            .shadow(radius: 3)
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }//ForEach
        }//VStack
    }
```

As far as I know – I am not an expert on the inner workings of the type inference engine – how this works is that when the type checker sees the `userView(user, books)`, because we've told it it will produce a view, it can stop there and then it separately checks the types for the body of the ViewBuilder itself.

I think your intuition is correct, I have found that `if` statements within SwiftUI code really gives the type checker a hard time.

Comment: This is a great answer that works for the provided code. One follow-up error that came up is ```Missing argument for parameter #1 in call```. It showed up in the userView function right next to the ForEach statement: ```ForEach(user.loved, id: \.self) { item in```. Let me know if you have any thoughts on the error and if there are any initializations I need to make to access both books and user fully and pass them on to other views like .sheet etc. Thank you very much @idz this really helped me out and I will upvote + award when this small error resolves.

Comment: @AbenezerBayeh normally that means you forgot to pass something in to the ViewBuilder and your class has a member variable with the same name. For example, it you were to delete the books parameter in the code I sent posted, you would see this. The problem is that compiler tries to use `self.books` which is not the correct type. If you post the exact code you are using, I might be able to help you out.

Comment: thank you for mentioning that, I had forgot to pass in some State values needed for the complex code. Thank you so much again, your answer was perfect and my code works now!